# How to escape curly braces in razor (e.g. to define an array)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arrays, razor, curly-braces

In Razor view I can define an array easily

```
@{  
    ViewBag.Title = "_Navigation";
    var foo = new string[0];
}
```

But if I want to define the elements of the string, the natural way would be

```
@{  
    ViewBag.Title = "_Navigation";
    var foo = new string[]{"foo", "bar"};
}
```

The latter doesn't work. Can you tell me why and how to define my foo-array properly?

============ EDIT ============

you are absolutely right, there is nothing wrong. The code i actually used was

```
@{  
    ViewBag.Title = "_Navigation";
    var action = @ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");  
    var foo = new string[]{"foo", "bar"};
}
```

and somehow the @ sign before my line in question coused the compiler to complain. I don't know why the @ was there - code was not from me... ok, it works now.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: It works for me. There must be something else in your code that's throwing of the parser.

Comment: Can you provide some definition for "doesn't work"?

Comment: Basically, I had the very same problem and apparently I made exactly the same mistake (unnecessary @ prefix) as you did! Without this question I'd still be trying to figure out what's wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with how you're defining the array.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_Navigation";
    var foo = new string[]{"foo", "bar"};
}
...
@foreach(var f in foo)
{
    <span>@f</span>
}
```

Prints

```
<span>foo</span><span>bar</span>
```